# Win32com.client text-to-speech

Tags: python, python-3.x, win32com

I am looking at making a Siri/Cortana/JARVIS thing with python, I have got the speech-to-text and the basic AI working, though I am having problems with the text-to-speech. I am on windows 10 and Python 3.6. Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client
class Voice(object):
    def __init__(self, id, name=None, languages=[], gender=None, age=None):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.languages = languages
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return '''<Voice id=%(id)s
          name=%(name)s
          languages=%(languages)s
          gender=%(gender)s
          age=%(age)s>''' % self.__dict__
def _toVoice(attr):
    return Voice(attr.Id, attr.GetDescription())
def _tokenFromId(id, speaker):
    tokens = speaker.GetVoices()
    for token in tokens:
        if token.Id == id: return token
    raise ValueError('unknown voice id %s', id)
class Zira():
    def __init__(self):
        self.speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch('SAPI.SpVoice')
        self.voices = self.speaker.GetVoices()
        self.voice = _toVoice(self.voices.Item(1))
        self.speaker.Voice = _tokenFromId(self.voice.id, self.speaker)
    def say(self, text):
        self.speaker.Speak(text)
class David():
    def __init__(self):
        self.speaker = win32com.client.Dispatch('SAPI.SpVoice')
        self.voices = self.speaker.GetVoices()
        self.voice = _toVoice(self.voices.Item(0))
        self.speaker.Voice = _tokenFromId(self.voice.id, self.speaker)
    def say(self, text):
        self.speaker.Speak(text)
```

I have just moved from Python 3.5 to 3.6, it worked fine in 3.5, but not now in 3.6. I installed win32 via pip. My error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    n = Zira()
  File "C:\Users\Public\Benjys_Python\xspeaker.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.speaker.Voice = _tokenFromId(self.voice.id, self.speaker)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 565, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)
```

Comment: You might need to use the [COM makepy utility](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.4/pywin32/html/com/win32com/HTML/GeneratedSupport.html), but I've no experience with it.

Comment: Also, see [pyttsx](http://pyttsx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: were you able to make this work ?